# how to publish c# database project

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have created a C# database project in Visual Studio 2010 and tried to publish as a normal project, but its not storing values in database. I have database file.mdf and connection string `'Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\fkr\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Management\Management\Mgt.mdf";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True'`

> I am working with database for the first time and i'm not having any
>   idea about how to deal with it.

Please help...

Comment: What is the error you are encountering with?

Comment: i am not getting an error. it gets published and when i run it, i cant change values in database

Comment: Share your code

Comment: the code is working fine because it is storing values in debug mode. but when published, it dont stores values

Answer (score 0):

You have to replicate your database from development machine to the server.

There is an option of publishing a database in Visual studio, steps for the same are:

`Right click` on the database and choose `publish to provide` that will present a dialog window to export your current database schema to a .sql format file which you have to import on the server to replicate the same database as of your development machine.

[image]

For more info refer this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1LUrUJ2cnc